# foreign key constraint error 1005

Tags: mysql, database

I have following 2 tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `entity_creation_timestamp` datetime default NULL,
  `entity_version` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `county` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `line1` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `line2` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `line3` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zip_extension` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `party_id` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `list_index` int(11) default NULL,
  `last_updated_timestamp` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `fk_party_postaladdress_id` (`party_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_party_postaladdress_id` FOREIGN KEY (`party_id`) REFERENCES `sims_party` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

the other one :

```
CREATE TABLE `state` (
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`state`),
  KEY `pk_state` (`state`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I am trying to apply a foreign key constraint on 'state' column in 'address' table to 'name' column in the 'state' table..

the command i am using for the same is :

```
ALTER TABLE address
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_address_state FOREIGN KEY (state)
    REFERENCES state(state) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

But each time I run this command, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'db.#sql-75c_da' (errno: 150)
```

Any idea where its going wrong...???

Comment: What kind of database? which engine? -- Edit : Just noticed its InnoDB, maybe you should make it clearer in the question and the tags.

Comment: Your DDL runs without error on MySQL 5.5 after removing the `fk_party_postaladdress_id` constraint. (Removed because you didn't post DDL for the table it references.)

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL reports an error number 1005 from a CREATE TABLE statement, and the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. Similarly, if an ALTER TABLE fails and it refers to error 150, that means a foreign key definition would be incorrectly formed for the altered table. To display a detailed explanation of the most recent InnoDB foreign key error in the server, issue `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html